# How To Fic NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: noclassdeffounderror

im trying to upload files using FTP client when i deploy my application on my local machine it upload files to the server without any issue BUT when i use same application on the server to upload files to the same server i got this exception

ERROR TP-Processor719 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[jodads.com].[/ShayaktiAdmin].[UploadItem] - Servlet.service() for servlet UploadItem threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/http/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload
    at com.shayakti.servlet.UploadItemServlet.processRequest(UploadItemServlet.java:99)
    at com.shayakti.servlet.UploadItemServlet.doPost(UploadItemServlet.java:424)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:311)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

before i post this i try to figure out what is the problem and do some search most of posts tell that common-io is missing from the server lib so i download the common-io jar and add it to my application then re uploaded to the server but there is no hope :(

i do contact the server host support and they tell me that tomcat i use on my local machine contains some lib that not provided in server tomcat !!!

im hopeless i dont what should i do !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of tomcat is on the server?  Looks like ServletFileUpload was introduced in tomcat 7. http://mavenhub.com/c/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload/jar